# How to align the information using CSS grid?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to display the details in a nice detailed layout and make it responsive. But I am unable to do it as expected using **CSS** grid. Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/HebleV/pen/qPVVYo).

Currently this is how it looks.

[image: img]

But this is how I want it to be.

[image: img1]

**HTML Code**

```
<div class="mainContent">
    <div class="mainContent__stuff">
        <div><img src="cup.jpg" width="75" height="75" class="circle" /></div>
        <div>
            <p>Style & Accessory has been approved.</p>
            <p>An endorsement for Apple Watch</p>
            <h5>Subscribers-12344</h5>
            <h5>Female-92.4</h5>
            <h5>Male-7.6</h5>
        </div>
        <div><img src="cup.jpg" width="105" height="105"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
.wrapper .mainContent {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-column: 4/10;
    grid-row: 6/14;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mainContent .mainContent__stuff {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column: 4/10;
}
```

Comment: We don't need your entire codebase in the Demo....a **mimimal** demo is required. Please make a reduced case!

Comment: This sounds like homework, please include what you have tried so far and did not work.

Comment: @Paulie_D Fair enough. Have updated the codepen

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Can you see the code that I tried along with question?

Comment: I did, that did not seem like trying something, you layed all your paragraphs and titles inside the `<div>` and expected it to just work ? Where is the code where you created the layout for the counts ? Or the blue cercle border for the left image ? Or the vertical line between Subscribers and Female ?

Comment: How is that blue circle or that Female forms a requirement for answering. I am just want a layout not a complete design. Even a simple example would do. @GhassenLouhaichi

Comment: It's a direct requirement in your question as you litterally said "But this is how I want it to be". So please elaborate your question to indicate exactly what you need from the layout of the second screenshot.

Comment: @GhassenLouhaichi Didn't you read the title? I said align and you read only "this is how I want it to be". Read the question mate again. I just want a layout using grid.

Answer (score 1):

You want to restructure your HTML and use the flexbox approach. You can change your HTML as follows to give more structure to it and allow more playability with CSS for it :

```
<div>
    <p><b>Style & Accessory</b> has been approved.</p>
    <p>An endorsement for Apple Watch</p>
    <div class="counts">
        <div class="first">
            <div>Subscribers</div>
            <div>12,344</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>Female</div>
            <div>92.4%</div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>Male</div>
            <div>7.6%</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can this way use CSS magic to display your contents the way you like using flexbox :

```
.mainContent__stuff {
    display: flex;
    color: gray;
}

.mainContent__stuff div {
    flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.mainContent__stuff div .counts {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.mainContent__stuff div .counts div {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.mainContent__stuff div .counts .first {
    border-right: 2px solid lightgray;
}
```

Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/glouhaichi/pen/PJOjWV) illustrating the behavior in a example.

Comment: Hey thanks mate. is it also possible to implement this using css grid?

Comment: I'm not really the expert on the grid layout, I am just a flexbox enthusiast.